# How to promote the site at a local crypto party?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Short question, what would the best way to promote the site at a local crypto party?

Answer (score 4):

If you are up for doing a bit of work beforehand, you could print out a few cards having the URL and QR code of the site, and hand them out at the party.

A tangible reminder will be more effective.

<sub>Also, the folks over at [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) ([chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot)) are pretty helpful. I am sure any of them will help you out if you want to make a good looking card ;)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Handing everyone the site url (http://tor.stackexchange.com) and ask them kindly to contribute perhaps?